# Which MAC address is the right one?

Tags: windows, mac, ip, wireless-access-point

Result by 'getmac':

```
C:\>getmac

Physical Address    Transport Name
=================== ==========================================================
72-03-C6-48-59-34   \Device\Tcpip_{8AEB3263-18C4-449E-A80F-BC2541DDC2A9}
00-21-9B-D5-6F-EE   \Device\Tcpip_{C2F9CE19-D68F-4105-9766-45CBE6D82331}
00-22-68-D2-9B-F7   \Device\Tcpip_{A2701130-9221-43FE-8F14-7B1114F84DC3}
```

Result by 'ipconfig /all':

```
C:\>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

        Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : xps-m1530
        Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
        Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Mixed
        IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Wireless Network Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Dell Wireless 1395 WLAN Mini-Card
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-22-68-D2-9B-F7
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration IP Address. . . : 169.254.246.4
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Marvell Yukon 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Eth
ernet Controller
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-21-9B-D5-6F-EE
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.112
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
        DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
        DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                            8.8.4.4
        Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 01 November 2012 9:00:36 AM
        Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 04 November 2012 9:00:36 AM
```

There is a MAC address on the back of my laptop, but the sticker is no longer there. So I use the 'getmac' command to get the MAC addresses. But which address shown by 'getmac' above is the one matching the MAC in the sticker on the back of my laptop?

Or am I mistaken something?

00-21-... is the ethernet adapter, 00-22-... is the wireless adapter, and 72-03-... is what?

Comment: There is absolutely no way we could know which MAC address was on the sticker of your laptop without looking at it. It's entirely possible the sticker held the MAC address of your wired Ethernet interface. But it's also possible it held the MAC address of the WiFi interface. How could we possibly know what was on the sticker by any method other than looking at it?

Comment: yeah, that is the problem. the sys admin at my office requires the MAC address of my laptop. but the sticker is gone! oh mine!

Comment: You may prefer to use `ipconfig /all` as that will make it easier to determine which MAC corresponds to which adapter - just look for the physical address properties

Comment: i've updated the question with info printed out by ipconfig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to spell it out, you have two network devices (wired and wireless) and therefore two MAC addresses. 00-21-9B-D5-6F-EE is the address of the wired one.

00-22-68-D2-9B-F7 is the address of the wireless card and is probably the one your sysadmin wants.

Comment: and 72-03-C6-48-59-34?

Comment: Hmm, doesn't correspond to any known MAC vendor - probably an error or an unused VPN interface.

Comment: That's a multicast [LAA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Address_details) (locally administered address).

Comment: oh, LAA :) i see